# How to efficiently pass video frames using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, video

I need to open an .mp4 video file and analyze frames sequentially at a certain time interval. I am working with Python and openCV. At the moment my solution is:

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
for i in interval:
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,i)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    if success:
        perform_analysis()
    else:
        break
```

but I wonder if such solution is optimal, since the instruction ´vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,i)´ could pass all frames up to i-1 each time ( i.e. I do not know if mp4 format and OpenCV really support efficient random access ). Are there faster solutions ?

Comment: do not seek. generally unreliable (OpenCV), only works well for some codecs/encodings. -- random access is only efficient if you allow it to jump to keyframes and stay there, i.e. if you allow it to be imprecise. if you require precise positioning, it'll cost almost as much as a complete decode (skip to keyframe, decode P/B frames). -- if you require seeking, you might have to look into ffmpeg's API. PyAV is the only proper wrapper of those APIs I know of. -- or just loop over all frames and discard all frames you don't want -- you might wanna know of "presentation timestamps" (PTS)

Comment: Thanks!. You have put a lot of information in your comment, I am not sure I am able to follow all of it. But overall what is your suggestion ? I do not require seeking by itself, I just want to reach the goal of looping over the frames, with a certain interval between them, as fast as possible (NB: the perform_analysis function uses OpenCV ).